# Update Dependent Dropdown Menu PHP, Jquery, Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, menu, dropdown

**Goals2 Table:**

| id | game_number_id | team_id_goal | player_id_goal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

**Teams Table:**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | MTL |
| 2 | BOS |
| 3 | CGY |
| 4 | EDM |

**Players table:**

| id | team_id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Kirby | Dach |
| 2 | 1 | Juraj | Slafkovsky |
| 3 | 2 | Brad | Marchand |
| 4 | 2 | Patrice | Bergeron |

I have a dependent drop down menu containing two options to select: First option gets data from table A called "teams". Second option gets data from table B called "players". "Players" is dependent on the first option "teams". Once user selects their team, the second option will show them all players for that specific team only. After submitting, they will be stored in a separate table called "goals2".

These two ("teams & players") together equal one record. I can add as many as I'd like into my database one by one.

Now when I am updating these records, I pull all the records from the 3rd table "goals2", where these records were stored, and display them all on the page (with the same dropdown menu format included so that i can edit before re-submitting).

These records are displayed through a foreach loop and here is where my dropdown functionality breaks down.

For example if there are three records: the first option "teams" will work for all three, however the dependent option "players" will only work for the first record, and will be dependent on whichever last "teams" option was selected (on any record).

How can I have multiple records each with their own dependent drop downs? Without having them interfere with each other?

Been at this all weekend. I think it may have something to do with a missing IF statement or FOR loop? Or a counter of some sort? Running out of ideas. Would love to figure out how to fix this.

Here is my PHP:

```
$id=$_GET['updateid2'];


//Below is just a query to get all the records i want to display on the page:
$sql5="SELECT goals2.id AS goalsid, goals2.game_number, goals2.team_id_goal, goals2.player_id_goal,
teams.id, teams.name,
players.team_id, players.first_name, players.last_name
 FROM goals2
JOIN teams ON goals2.team_id_goal = teams.id
JOIN players ON goals2.player_id_goal = players.id
WHERE goals2.game_number = $id
";

$statement5=$pdo->prepare($sql5);
$statement5->execute();
$results5 = $statement5->fetchAll();


//Below is query for option A "teams":
$sql6="SELECT id, name FROM teams";
$statement6 = $pdo->prepare($sql6);
$statement6->execute();
$results6=$statement6->fetchAll();


?>

//Below is my form.There are two foreach loops. First foreach ($result5) is to display
//all the records on the page. The second foreach($result6) is just for the option A "teams"
//so that the dropdown menu can fetch all the teams:
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<form name="insert" action="user2.php?updateid2=<?=$id;?>" method="post">
Game number: <?=$id;?>
<br>

<?php foreach($results5 as $result5){ ?>
<?=$result5['goalsid'];?>
  Team:
    <select onChange="getplayer(this.value);">
<option value="">Select</option>

<?php foreach($results6 as $result6){ ?>
 
    <option value="<?php echo $result6['id'];?>"><?php echo $result6['name'];?></option>
<?php } ?>


</select>
<br>
Player: <select id="players-dependent">
<option value="">Select</option>
</select>
   <?php } ?>

<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Here is my Jquery:

```
function getplayer(val) {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "user3.php",
data:'id='+val,
success: function(data){
$("#players-dependent").html(data);
}
});
}
```

Here is my User3.php file that Ajax triggers dependent drop down once first option is selected:

```
<?php
include 'database-connection.php';
if(!empty($_POST["id"])) 
{
$playerid=$_POST["id"];
$sql="SELECT team_id, first_name, last_name FROM players WHERE team_id=:teamid";
$statement2 = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$data = [':teamid'=>$playerid];
$statement2->execute($data);    
$results2 = $statement2->fetchAll();
}
?>
<option value="">Select District</option>
<?php foreach($results2 as $result2){ ?>
    <option value="<?=$result['id'];?>"><?=$result2["first_name"].' '.$result2['last_name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Is this a PHP problem, or an AJAX problem? Also, keep in mind that some of your queries are widely open for SQL injection. Use prepared statements **everywhere** to avoid getting hacked

Comment: @NicoHaase both i think. It feels like AJAX is assuming all the records in foreach loop belong to one single record. WHen it should instead recognize them as their own unique record

Comment: AJAX does not know anything about "records". Check whether the browser sends the data in the proper format to the server, whether the server reads that data properly, and whether the server sends the data the browser expects to rule that out